# WeakReference and memory leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks, weak-references

I'm profiling my application using VisualVM and I see that the heap size increased by about 7MB in about 3 days. When I use memory sampler, I also see that `java.lang.ref.WeakReference` is in the top five for the instances number. The number of `WeakReference` is increasing and GC has almost no effect.

Any idea?

Comment: So where are you using weak references?

Comment: 7Mb in three days is nothing for a java app. Why do you think you have a memory leak?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not using Weak references directly in my application. But maybe I'm using libraries that do use them.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy Why 7MB is nothing for a java app? I don't want that in two months, the heap size will grow by 100MB?!

Comment: @MickaelMarrache: 7MB in the course of three days really isn't very much. Even growing by 100MB in the course of two months really isn't a lot. It could be that these objects are just not being collected *yet*. How much activity have you had in those 3 days?

Comment: @JonSkeet I understand that the only solution is to wait? Is there a way to know if it's a memory leak? During these 3 days, the application was running in a normal fashion. This is an application that uses Spring Batch. It reads data from a file, does some processing and writes the records in a database.

Comment: @MickaelMarrache: "A normal fashion" doesn't really tell us anything about how much work it was doing. If it only ever had to perform one operation in those three days, I'd have some concerns. If it had been really busy, doing a lot of of work over those three days and generating millions of objects, then a change of only 7MB indicates that if there *is* a leak, it's a very small one. It would be worth seeing what still had a reference to those WeakReference objects though.

Comment: @JonSkeet It seems that a big number of WeakReference are stored in an Object[] and it seems related to logging, but I don't know if these objects are concerned by the increase of instances number. There are also MethodDescriptor instances that reference WeakReference instances.

Comment: @Jon, the weak references are quite commonly leaked, not the holding object by the references themselves... and the worst come when they are extended (not just java.lang.ref.WeakReference) which is the usual use in maps/threadlocal. I consider all leaks evil, they accumulate in the old-gen which makes the full collection slower and slower.

Comment: @Mickael, take a memory dump and analyze it, you can track the leak source. Usually tracking leaks (provided you have an idea what classes might be causing it) is pretty straightforward process.

Comment: @bestsss I took a memory dump but I don't know how to determine who continues to create new WeakReference instances.

Comment: @Mickael, 1st you need to determine who holds the references towards and then trace the code. If you have some profiling tool that allows stack trace recording on creation, you can use that. Alternatively replacing the WeakRefeence in the boot classpath `-Xbootclasspath/p:` and add an exception to hold the stack trace is an option as well. However, almost always it's enough to see who holds the references towards and just examine the code  - I always do so and takes like 20-30mins to trace a leak.

Comment: @bestsss Okay, but it seems WeakReference class is used by multiple component. So, how can I know who's causing the increase of instances number? A head dump only shows me the number of WeakReferences instances and who holds each one of them.

Comment: @Mickael, that's your task. You can either compare heap dumps, or look which Object[] has the increasing amount. If you suspect any code (path)/library start off there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4597/discussion-between-bestsss-and-mickael-marrache)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have a memory leak.

Java's GC only runs when the heap is full (actually is a bit more complicated since the heap itself is divided into generations, but anyway), so unless you are filling the heap (which is very unlikely since 7Mb is too little memory for any heap) you can't tell wether you have a leak or not.

`WeakReferences` are small wrappers that actually help preventing memory leaks by marking the objet they reference as elegible for GC. My guess is that you're including some kind of cache library that creates a bunch of these, and since the heap still has plenty of room there's no need to garbage collect them.

Again, unless you see that the GC runs often and your heap size **still** increases I wouldn't worry about memory issues.

Here's [a great article on this matter](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.refobj)

Comment: When I said "increased by about 7MB", I was meaning that the heap size increased from 23MB to 30MB, not that my heap size increased to 7MB.(Sorry, English is not my primary language.) And like I said, I don't understand how the number of WeakReference instance can increase continuously without memory leak. A few minutes after the application started (normal work), the number of WeakReference instances was about 5000. And it increased until about 55000 after 3 days. Maybe the instances are still referenced but I don't understand by who.

Comment: has your gc __ever__ run? if not then don't worry. Also somewhere else you talked about your concern that the heap will grow __in years__? dude, come on... you will obviously change and redeploy this app a few times in months, not years.

Comment: That years comment actually makes me thing your trolling us over here

Comment: Okay, I'm new in the programming world. I've started to work three months ago after my studies. I didn't know that generally an application is redeployed many times a year. But it's also interesting to understand what it's happening here (if something really happens).

Comment: Alright. The article I linked is awesome to understand garbage collection in java. Also to confirm a leak you should see the heap filling to it's top, being garbage collected to (say) 30mb, then reaching the top again, being GC and down to 35mb, then to 40mb, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

WeakReferences are the among first to get collected in case the JVM runs a full GC, however, they must not be strongly/ softly reachable (no strong/ soft reference must be holding a reference to it). I am usually least worried about WeakReferences, they do get GC-ed eventually. You should check your GC cycles (jstat) and see if even GC is not claiming these references. Also, please do not extrapolate the leak, your application may not necessarily grow its memory consumption in the next few days. I would suggest running a long (48 hr?) performance test with a significant load on a non production environment and see if you run into memory issues.

Comment: Let's clarify that a *WeakReference* is an instance of an object itself; even if/when the *referenced* object is gone the WeakReference itself may still be strongly reachable and, thus, not be collected.

Comment: @HannoBinder So, that's a problem, no? (because the WeakReference instances take place in the heap?)

Comment: Just supplementing aishwarya's answer, I mean that, in *theory*, yes, it *could* be a cause of a memory leak. I don't believe it is in this case, though. Have you had a look at not only the *instance count* but also at the *amount of heap memory* that's used by various classes of objects?

Comment: I agree with others, by the way, that 7mb is *not* significant for even the simplest of Java applications; that's more like normal heap "jitter", if you will. Maybe try to build a small sample application which runs a loop allocating and releasing objects repeatedly. I think you will observe a similar "memory leak".

Answer (score 1):

VisualVM uses resources in the system.  This is one of its weakness compared with commercial profilers.  As such small differences cannot be easily seen with VisualVM because it creates its own noise.

Lets say you have a leak of 7 MB in 3 days (which I doubt). How much times is it worth you spending to fix it? 16 GB of memory costs about $100 so 7 MB is worth about 5 cents, or about 3 seconds of your time.  I would worry about it more if it were larger, much larger.

Comment: I understand the tradeoff, but if there is a leak, this is a "problem". The application is supposed to run continuously, and after a long time (say years), the heap size would be greater. And I understand from the previous comments that it may slow the application because the old generation may contain a big number of objects.

Comment: It sounds like you have a collection of WeakReferences. If you have such, you need to periodically remove the WeakReferences.  This is because while the object they reference are cleaned up they are not themselves removed automatically.

Comment: 7 MB/3days is still only 800 MB per years.  I don't imagine you wouldn't be able to restart the application in that time.

Comment: @Peter, leaks increase the heap in the old gen causing slower GC, esp full GC. It's not only purely the price of the memory.